# require_entry problems with more than 2 segment

Tags: channel-entries, channel, entries, redirects, segments

```
www.cooking/recipes/apple_pie
```

The first Expression Engine segment (recipes) represent the recipes channel, and the second segment represent an entry (here apple_pie)

If an entry doesn't exist or is misspelled, i use this code to redirect to the 404 page, and it works fine:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="recipes" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
          {exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
                {if no_results}
                        {redirect="error/404"}
                {/if}
           {/exp:ifelse}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But if I add a segment (dessert), always have redirect to the 404 page, even if the entry exist. Without the redirect code the entries pages like (www.cooking/recipes/dessert/apple_pie) works fine, but i lose the redirect function.

```
www.cooking/recipes/dessert/apple_pie
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Lol, well what **are** desserts? Is that a channel category? Using Solspace Tag? Is desserts a different channel?

Comment: Hi Jrothafe!! Desserts are something delicious !! Yes it's a channel category related to "recipes channel", not a Solspace tag, not a channel.

Comment: hummmm it's a category,

Comment: So do you want both www.cooking/recipes/dessert/apple_pie **and** www.cooking/recipes/apple_pie to load your apple_pie entry?

Comment: only one: www.cooking/recipes/dessert/apple_pied. Dessert exist as a category, in this case the segment dessert is linked with a condition inside the main recipes template: if {segment_2} == 'dessert' (template code). So if the segment 2 = dessert the main recipes template will display the specific code for the specific condition (if {segment_2} == 'dessert').

Answer (score 1):

https://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/urls/template_routes.html

Template routes! These things are your friend. On your template, you want to set a template route that looks like this:

```
/recipes/{section:category}/{section:alpha_dash}
```

Set that template to require all routes. Then bam:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="{segment_1}" category="{segment_2}" url_title="{segment_3}" limit="1" require_entry="yes"}
      {exp:ifelse parse="inward"}
            {if no_results}
                    {redirect="error/404"}
            {/if}
       {/exp:ifelse}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

This should do the trick, no?

Comment: Jrothafer, thanks for your fast help and reply !! I thought about routes, but until today I did not catch how it works (lack of documentation). I will analyze with more calm today your solution, and at the same time i will try to catch Templates route eating desserts ;)

Comment: The Ellislab Templates routes documentation is not very clear,  it sounds incomplete to understand how it works.  I tried the template routes but it returns a blank page with a message:  undefined.....

Comment: I'll see if I can do some testing on a dev server today.. No promises though!

Comment: On a side note, I found the EE router much more understandable after I'd read and understood the CodeIgniter Router (after all, its what EE is built on!), which is documented also. Check it out it may help you out.

Comment: Hi Blatant, now I understand better the the EE router. Using 2 segments , the channel entries with require_entry="yes" to redirect if the entry no exists works fine. But it doesn't work using 3 segments. If I use a variable in the second segment in a route template: /recipes/{cat:alpha_dash}/{section:alpha_dash},  a blank screen appears with this message: This web page is not available : ERR_CONTENT_DECODING_FAILED. So i will stay with only 2 segment about entries and redirect.With 3 segments, it sounds complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my understanding of the issue...

Try this:

> {exp:channel:entries channel="recipes" url_title="**{if segment_2 != 'dessert'}{segment_2}{if:else}{segment_3}{/if}**" limit="1" require_entry="yes" **dynamic="no"**}

If there's only dessert category then I think this should work, unless you have other categories, then you'll have to update the if statement.